# Command-line PDF optimizer (linearizer)

Tags: linux, pdf, command-line

I'm looking for a **Linux** command line util that inputs a merged **PDF** (between 1mb and 500mb) and outputs an optimized/linearized version. Each and every page uses the same set of ~8 images, and the same font.  Running one of my test files through *Adobe Acrobat Pro* took the file from 34MB to 1.6MB in a matter of about 30 seconds. I'm not really expecting performance like that, but something even half as fast/efficient would be wonderful.

I need it for a batched job running on **Linux**, which is why it needs a CLI.  I've tried **pdftk**, **gs**, **qpdf**, **pdftops**, and **pdfsizeopt**. The first 4 are either far too slow or don't fully optimize the **pdf** files. **pdfsizeopt** seems promising, but I'm having trouble with consistency -- some of my **pdf**s will work, others will throw errors.

Any ideas other than what I've already listed? I wouldn't even mind purchasing something if it did the job.

Comment: Linearization and file size are not directly related... can you clarify precisely what you want?

Comment: @Alec Sanger: If my answer was helpful to you, then please consider marking it as the [accepted answer](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) so others may more easily find it in the future. This is also a polite way to thank the person answering your question for helping you out.

Answer (score 10):

I personally use Ghostscript to optimize the size of my PDF files. You can specify an *optimization level* and it will shrink the pictures. This also has the (IMHO desirable) side-effect of removing elements that are outside the page margins.

```
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFSETTINGS=/printer -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -r75 -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile="output.pdf" "input.pdf"
```

[The levels you can use](http://milan.kupcevic.net/ghostscript-ps-pdf/) are:

```
-dPDFSETTINGS=/screen (screen-view-only quality, 72 dpi images)
-dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook (low quality, 150 dpi images)
-dPDFSETTINGS=/printer (high quality, 300 dpi images)
-dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress (high quality, color preserving, 300 dpi imgs)
-dPDFSETTINGS=/default (almost identical to /screen)
```

Comment: For anyone wondering, this yields much better compression than pdfsizeopt

Comment: I may be the only one who got bit by this, but it was bad enough I thought I'd leave a comment.  `gs` is a very common alias (especially for git status).  If you're getting an error message, double check that it's not aliased `type gs` or use the full name `ghostscript` instead of `gs` .  Also confirmed working on Fedora (Linux) ghostscript v9.55.0

Answer (score 2):

PdfCpu works great:

```
pdfcpu optimize in.pdf out.pdf
```

https://pdfcpu.io/core/optimize

Comment: `pdfcpu` choked on a pdfs that were created from a google doc with error: `dereferenceObject: problem dereferencing object 69: pdfcpu: parse: duplicate key` .  However running it through GhostScript first (using other answer) first and then pdfcpu optimize afterward yielded better results than ghostscript alone.

Comment: are you a dev or otherwise affiliated with the project?  I can't share the pdf from yesterday but I can try to reproduce it with a pdf that is redistributable

Comment: @Freedom_Ben I am a Go expert, so I might be able to help